# How to create dynamic text?

Tags: python

What i have to do to display text dynamic?

`Some text [-]` to go `Some text [|]` and then back to `Some text [-]`.

Is there a way to do this without clearing whole screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a POSIX terminal you can use two techniques:

- Write a `\r` carriage return to go back to start of the line
- Write a `\b` backspace to clear a few characters.

In both cases, I'd use `sys.stdout.write()` together with a flush to write this out.

Using `\b` backspace demo:

```
import sys
import time
sys.stdout.write('Some text [\\]')
for i in ['-', '/', '|', '\\'] * 10:
    sys.stdout.write('\b\b\b[{0}]'.format(i))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Using `\r` carriage return demo:

```
import sys
import time
for i in ['-', '/', '|', '\\'] * 10:
    sys.stdout.write('\rSome text [{0}]'.format(i))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```